# Remove highlight from ListView items....deselecting

Tags: c#, listview

Basically I am writing a simple phone directory. This application has a listview window, a search (text) window and a button to search. Once the user inputs a name in the search window and hit the search button, the program selects and highlight all users corresponding to the search criteria.
No problem….

A unique scenario developed however if the user selects another item in the listview window. The previous items found are/will be still highlighted…

How can I deselect/remove the highlight on the found items whenever/ifever the user select another item immediately after the search?

Below is the code attached to the search button:

Thanks in advance

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        string s = "    Search Via Forename";
        int result = 0;
        int count = 0;
        result = string.Compare(textBox1.Text, s);

        switch ((result == 0) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))){
            case true: MessageBox.Show("Please input forename...");
                       break;
              default: foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
                          if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower())){
                             item.Selected = true;
                             item.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                             item.ForeColor = Color.White;
                             count++;
                          }else{
                             item.Selected = false;
                             item.BackColor = Color.White;
                             item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                          }
                       }
                       if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1){
                           listView1.Focus();
                       }
                       textBox1.Text = "    Search Via Forename";
                       textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
                       break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your highlightning code, make a loop through all the items and set their *item.Selected* to false.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){ 
    if (item.Selected)
        item.Selected = false;
}
```

Comment: If i'm reading the question correctly, this doesn't answer it.  He is having an issue where, after performing the search, the user clicks one of the items in the list.  After clicking something in the list he wants all other selections to clear.

Comment: Ah, I see. Still, loop through and deselect all items, except the chosen one I would say.

Answer (score 0):

First removed the selection piece of your code. In fact I would just clear selections all together. The color change that your doing is effectively doing the highlighting for you, so from the information you've provided I don't think its necessary to select them.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string s = "    Search Via Forename";
    int result = 0;
    int count = 0;
    result = string.Compare(textBox1.Text, s);

    switch ((result == 0) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))){
        case true: MessageBox.Show("Please input forename...");
                   break;
          default: foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
                         item.Selected = false;
                      if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower())){                             
                         item.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                         item.ForeColor = Color.White;
                         count++;
                      }else{
                         item.BackColor = Color.White;
                         item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                      }
                   }
                   if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1){
                       listView1.Focus();
                   }
                   textBox1.Text = "    Search Via Forename";
                   textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
                   break;
    }
}
```

Next I would use the selection changed event to detect when a selection was made and clear all the formatting I did.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            item.BackColor = Color.White;
            item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

You didn't specify win forms or WPF so I assumed win forms and made an example that way.  If your using WPF i believe the event you would need to subscribe to is the OnSelectionChanged event for the list view control.

After looking at the code a bit more, I realize your using a switch statement to handle a Boolean operation which is not correct.  I've added how I would have changed that check below.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "    Search Via Forename";
        int result = 0;
        int count = 0;
        result = string.Compare(textBox1.Text, s);

        // Do the check on the input
        if ((result == 0) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please input forename...");
            // after notifying the user just return
            return;
        }
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            item.Selected = false;
            if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                item.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
                item.ForeColor = Color.White;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                item.BackColor = Color.White;
                item.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            listView1.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hack... sorry bout this but, from where exactly should I delete from. could you please elaborate more... and thanks for your help!

Comment: @BOB.G in the first code snippet i added i removed the item.select lines from your provided code and added one higher up to handle deselecting all.  Essentially i removed the item.select from the if else, and put one before the if that deselects all items.   does that help?

Comment: Hack, hi... after copying your modifications, the result was a bit better than what I had before. However, there are two new issues. (1) After inserting the search string, you have to click the search button twice before the result(s) is/are highlighted. (2) Once the names are  highlighted and you move the mouse towards a name, everything retreat back to normal, even before you reach the target name. The ideal behaviour would be having the names highlighted until the mouse is actually on one, then the others go back to normal. Once again, thanks for your help. Hope its not too difficult to fix

Comment: For the first issue, I'm not sure.  I can't reproduce this. Very strange.  I suspect it has something to do with how your doing the "Hue" text (the string Search Via Forename).  for your second issue.  The only thing i can think of is that you put the code i posted into either a focus or mouse over event rather then the SelectionChanged/SelectedIndexChanged event. can you verify you are setting the correct event handler?

Comment: Hack, hi...  hope you had a good weekend. Over the break I was considering modifying my design. Due to the length of the list (40 names) whenever a user search for a name and any of the result is below the list window, its a possible the user won't see it. So I am thinking of displaying the result in a window... Thanks for your help and I did put the code in listView1_SelectedIndexChanged. We will see how it goes..